# Unable to install 14.04 from boot disc on windows 8.1

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

I have followed [this](http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/)  guide to install ubuntu to the same drive as a pre-existing windows 8.1 installation. I have got up to installing ubuntu without any issues where I encounter either a blank screen or a distorted one after the dvd is read.

I have tried selecting `nomodeset`, `acpi=off` and `nolapic` before preceding to install ubuntu with no success (distorted screen).

DXDIAG : http://pastebin.com/nJhtWpMN

My machine is CSM capable and that option has been enabled in UEFI (disabling this stops windows booting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had to select try Ubuntu before installing and install through the live disc. I suggest trying this in addition to selecting nolapic + acpi=off to anyone encountering the same problem

Comment: Good man! and an upvote instead of a duplicate!  ;-)